# Symfony Controller return response not working

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Here is my code,

```
class LoginController
{
    public function authUser()
    {
        return "OK";
        exit();
    }
}
```

Its redirect to 404.
But if I use below code its working, what's wrong in first code.

```
class LoginController
{
    public function authUser()
    {
        return $this->render('test.html.php', array());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return an Response object like this :

```
class LoginController
{
    public function authUser()
    {
        return new Response("OK");
    }
}
```

https://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html